# Efficient method to find a value surrounded by zeros in a vector

Tags: matlab

I want to find and zero peaks in a vector with the shortest width, i.e. peaks that have a single sample being non-zero and the neighbouring samples zero, i.e. `[0 ~0 0]` with `~0` being the peak. Example: if `x = [1 0 2 0 0 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 0 8]`, then I want to find the 2, 3 and 7 and make them 0, i.e. `x` becomes `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 8]`. The following code does the trick, but is there a more efficient or better way to do this, or does a Matlab function exist that finds a certain pattern in a vector (or even matrix)?

```
% remove peaks of shape [0 ~0 0]
k = find(x);
for j=k'
    if j==numel(x) || j==1
    elseif ~x(j-1) && ~x(j+1)
        x(j) = 0;
    end
end
```

Comment: Can `x` contain both positive and negative numbers?

Comment: For completeness, could you also add the expected output related to your example input. Otherwise a very good [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for elements where the convolution with the kernel `[1,1,1]` does not differ with the original. The only complication is that we have to ignore the edge case:

```
x = [1 0 2 0 0 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 0 8];
y = conv(x,[1,1,1],'same');
ind = find(x==y);
x(ind(2:end-1)) = 0
```

or

```
x(find(x(2:end-1)==conv(x,[1,1,1],'valid'))+1) = 0
```

if faced with the prospect of both positive and negative numbers, then based on Craigim's suggestion in the comments:

```
xx = abs(x);
x(find(xx(2:end-1)==conv(xx,[1,1,1],'valid'))+1) = 0
```

Comment: Actually - this breaks down if you allow negative numbers, i.e. if `x = [1 0 2 0 0 3 0 4 5 -4 0 7 0 8]` then this method eliminates the `5` as well. Is that a problem for your use case?

Comment: Instead of convoluting with the original vector, convolute with `xx = x ~= 0'.

Comment: I like this answer best, because I wanted to do this with a convolution, but I was convolving with [0 1 0], which practically does nothing. Convolving with an array of `n` ones with `n` uneven will detect a single sample peak surrounded by `(n-1)/2` zeroes. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `[1,0,1]` and look where it returns zero instead of the original number I think...

Comment: Indeed, you can. But: it can also become 0 where x is 0, e.g. a sequence of three or more zeroes. You'd also have to check whether or not x is zero at that point, which is not hard.

Comment: @Erik yes that's what I was trying to imply by *instead*

Answer (score 5):

Using `conv` (along the lines of Dan's answer) is probably the best approach; but it can also be done with [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
x(strfind(x~=0, [0 1 0]) + 1) = 0;
```

Or using [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute a second-order difference:

```
x(find(diff(~x, 2)==2) + 1) = 0;
```

Comment: The `str` version doesn't work for me. `error: strfind: PATTERN must be a string or cell array of strings`

Comment: @kkuilla It does work in Matlab R2015a. But it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work in all versions, because using `strfind` with numbers is undocumented. What version are you using?

Comment: At the moment, GNU Octave Version 3.8.1 :-(

Comment: That must be it (Octave). I have tested in Matlab R2010b and R2015a, and it works

Comment: I should try it on R2006b later on. +1

Comment: Nice use of `strfind`, wouldn't have thought of that in such a context.

Comment: Very elegant to use `strfind`, but since its main use is for strings and this is more a programmatic solution instead of a more mathematical solution, I don't accept this as the answer. Maybe `strfind` converts all inputs to `char` (e.g. try `char([0 1 0])` or similarly `double('abc')`) and then it compares the strings, thus it finds equal strings instead of actually finding the double. Too bad `strfind.m` can't be read (at least, I can't find the actual `strfind` algorithm in any of the readably `strfind.m`-files.

Answer (score 5):

Here would be my way to do it

```
x_add = x(1:end-2) + x(2:end-1) + x(3:end);
x(find([0,x(2:end-1)==x_add,0]))=0;
```

It does add the previous value and the next value to each one and check which one didn't change

Comment: I like this, thanks! The code is a bit harder to read and therefore harder to understand than the other solutions, but its compact and quite smart.